# XUbuntu: disable system sounds

Tags: linux, audio, xfce

After updating to Xubuntu 18 the system started playing sounds when, for example, I cancel a command in Emacs, or the search in HTML page displayed in Firefox fails.  This is very inconvenient because this happens a lot and the sound played is very loud.

I don't know what produces this sound.  Kernel module `pcspkr` is not loaded.  I tried

```
xset -b
xset b off
```

Which also had no effect.

This is not a problem specific to console, however, console applications also play sounds.

When I tried set zeroth channel of alsa mixer to mute:

```
amixer set channel 0% mute
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'channel',0
```

But when I look at the output of `amixer`:

```
Simple mixer control 'Beep',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
```

I looked at `Settings > Appearance > Enable Sound Events`, but it's not ticked...

Short of opening the case and cutting off the beeper, I don't know what else to try.  Any ideas?

Comment: For me unloading `pcspkr` as described on the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PC_speaker#Disable_PC_Speaker) worked. What is the output of `lsmod | grep pcspkr`?